# How to determine the endianness of a wide string literal?

Tags: c++, c, string, unicode, character-encoding

I have known this problem is compiler-dependent. So I want a reliable method to determine.

For example:

```
const wchar_t str[] = L"飞流直下三千尺";
```

How should I know whether `str` is little-endian or big-endian?

Is there a compiler's guarantee that the endianness of a wide string literal is the same one as the target architectures?

Comment: Isn't this the same as detecting whether or not the machine is little endian? If so there are a million duplicates.

Comment: No. There is no guarantee that the endianness is that of the processor.

Comment: @xmllmx There is no guarantee that the endianness of e.g. `int` is that of the processor either. You detect the endianness of `wchar_t` the same way you would detect the endianness of `int`, except replacing `int` with `wchar_t`.

Comment: @hvd, the unicode endianness is unrelated to the processor's one, though they rooted in the same cause.

Comment: @xmllmx So again, it isn't any different from `int`. I'm not saying to detect `int`'s endianness, and assume `wchar_t` is stored the same way, I'm saying you can detect `wchar_t`'s endianness the same way you would that of `int`.

Comment: @hvd, thanks. I've got your meaning.

Comment: @hvd - This is actually a repeat of his own question that I left an answer to.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693016/ts-the-standard-defined-endianness-of-stdwstring/14693162#14693162

Comment: Thanks, left a note there. :)

Comment: Formally, `str` does not have any endianness; it's an array. Its **elements** can be big-endian or little-endian, so the question is more properly formulated "How to determine the endianness of `wchar_t`.

Comment: I can only add a recommendation to avoid L"" wide literals, as well as std::wstring. Use UTF8 literals in UTF=8 encoded source code file - all else is a mess. More in http://www.utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no compiler guarantee that `wchar_t` even *has* an endianness (or that it's Unicode, for that matter).